# .PHP specific Laravel route and NGINX issue

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, routes

I am deploying Laravel application on NGINX

I have a route specified in routes.php for handling non-blade php files and well as some of my blade php files

```
Route::any('/{pagephp}.php',function($pagephp) {
    return View::make($pagephp); //This will handle .PHP as well as blades
});
```

But I get No Input File specified error whenever I try to access files such as terms.blade.php
Note that I do not get error when I access specified routes. for e.g. I have signin.blade.php for which I have

```
Route::get('/signin',function() {
    return View::make('signin');
});
```

When looked in to error log I see

```
[error] 969#0: *91 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script:
/var/www/xxxx/public/terms.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response 
header from upstream, client: xxxxxxxx, server: xxxx, request: "GET /terms.php HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host:
```

As per the error, NGINX is trying to look for terms.php in public directory and not sending it to the route.php
Is there any way to fix this?

My NGINX config file is as follows

```
server {

# Port that the web server will listen on.
listen          80;

# Host that will serve this project.
server_name    xxxx;

# Useful logs for debug.
access_log      /var/www/xxxx/app/storage/logs/access.log;
error_log       /var/www/xxxx/app/storage/logs/error.log;
rewrite_log     on;

# The location of our projects public directory.
root            /var/www/xxxx/public;

# Point index to the Laravel front controller.
index           index.php;

location / {

    # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

}

# Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

# PHP FPM configuration.
location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

# We don't need .ht files with nginx.
location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}

# Set header expirations on per-project basis
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
        expires 365d;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If these files does not belongs to laravel framework they should not be on the directory but if in case you want to test a particular php script you can put that in public folder and that will be accessible via yourdomain.com/script.php